# powerpoint macro for selecting character

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How to individually select characters in a textframe w/o using

`For i = 1 To .Characters.Count` in powerpoint.

Just like in word(*.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend*).

Comment: Would help to explain a little more what you need to do, and why you don't want to use the `Characters` method

Comment: Like I want to position the cursor anywhere and then start selecting the character. Since obviously in the code above, I have to start at the first character. I guess what I'm trying to say is that I want the variable i to have the value of where I'm going to place the cursor. Not to have a predefined value or not being initialized at the first character position or let say on the fifth position. Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Textframe.Textrange
    .Characters(Start:=2, Length:=5).select
End with
```

will select 5 characters beginning with the second character in the specified shape object.

Comment: Hi Tim, I hope you're doing well. I think I kind of mislead you and I apologize for that. What I meant was something like this in ms word.

If I have "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 1234567890.:,; ' " (!?) +-*/=" as a text/string and place the cursor anywhere w/n the text/string in ms word and run the macro below, it will select character by character. That's what I'm trying to achieve in powerpoint and in as much as possible minus the For i = 1 To .Characters.Count statement.

Comment: Private Sub zxc()
  With Selection
    Do While .Range.Bookmarks.Exists("\EndOfDoc") = False
      .MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
      .Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
  End With
  MsgBox ("done")
End Sub 

Thanks once again.